# When store data including foreign key, errors occur in Django?

Tags: python, django, model

I'm developing django web service with Python3.5 and Django1.9.

I define models like belows:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class URLCategory(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField(null=True)
    site = models.ForeignKey(URLCategory, null=True) # site 라는 요소(프로퍼티)는 URLCategories 라는 클래스(모델)을 외래키로(MANY-TO-ONE) 가리킨다”이다.
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    crawl_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    num_of_comments = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, null=True)

    def save(self):
        self.crawl_date = timezone.now()
        super().save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And when I'm trying to do something like belows,

```
url_category = URLCategory("http://example.org")
post = Post(title="Title", created_date="06/29/2016", site=url_category)
post.save()
```

It occurs error, at `post.save()`:

```
self = <django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>, value = 'http://example.org'

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        value = super(AutoField, self).get_prep_value(value)
        if value is None:
            return None
>       return int(value)
E       ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "http://example.org"

../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:976: ValueError
```

I'm looking for same problems with keyword `invalid literal for int() with base 10` in `stackoverflow`, but can not solve this problem.

Need your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
url_category = URLCategory.objects.create(url="http://example.org")
post = Post(title="Title", created_date="06/29/2016", site=url_category)
post.save()
```

Comment: Awesome solution, it works! Thanks. By the way, when I'm trying to create multiple posts using for loop, all of which url is "http://example.org", duplicated url appears in category section in admin page. I want to make it appear only one time for the same url category, any ideas?

Comment: yes... using `get_or_create(url="example.com")` will create only one